# Drupal 7 - Destroying the session when the browser closes is not working on Chrome

Tags: sessions

Is there an issue with destroying the user session using Chrome? I've set this setting in settings.php: ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0) but it seems like Chrome ignores it or is it just caching the user session itself.

On IE and FF this works as intended. I've even set Chrome to not save user credentials but to no avail.

Any ideas please?

Comment: When you close your chrome browser and open it again. Does it open the last sites you were working on?

Comment: Yes it does. Could that be it? Is there a way around it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the Google Chrome browser

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with drupal session. The feature that remembers the opened tabs when the browser is closed is the root of your problem. The feature is named "On startup"  "Continue where I left off". Turn that off and you should be fine.